# When is the Blazor Client Site Stable Release Date

Tags: blazor

I'm starting with new Application in Blazor technology. Want to know when the stable release date? Everywhere it is just said May 2020. But No specific Date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release for `blazor-wasm-3.2` is scheduled on 19 May 2020.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/milestone/58

`blazor-wasm-3.2-rc` is planned for 30 April 2020.